# How Do I Run A Flash Game In Another Engine

Tags: windows, flash, customization

I have made a flash game called space jump and I dont want it to open in flashplayer when a person starts up the game I want the game to be in a plain window with a maximize button a minimize button and a exit button no about tabs or anything like that. My flash game is a projector so maybe you need flash to run the game but it opens in a plain window.

Comment: If you want a desktop game (and not a browser), you should look into using AIR. AIR executables can't be used in browser, and offers a bunch of useful functionalities (window manipulation, multiple windows, Filesystem access, game controlers...)

Comment: @Aralicia Hey Can I do that but without AIR, Air costs money adobe is so unfair =( But I guess They do program hard very hard!

Comment: Actually, you can freely download the AIR SDK, which gives you access to the AIR Framework and Compiler : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html Adobe isn't that unfair :p

Comment: @Aralicia Sorry but the air SDK is still too big for my internet speed their must be a under 20MB file that I can download?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

**Projector** is an exe right ? It can't be opened through Flash Player.
If you serve it as an `SWF`, It can be opened via Flash Player.